# Python MySQL query replaces created_at with updated_at

Tags: python, mysql

I have the following Python MySQL query:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Tweets(timestamp, message_id, body, username, symbol_id, created_at, updated_at) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE timestamp=VALUES(timestamp), message_id=VALUES(message_id), body=VALUES(body), username=VALUES(username), symbol_id=VALUES(symbol_id), created_at=NOW(), updated_at=NOW()"% \
(timestamp, messageId, body, username, dbID, currentTime, currentTime)
```

Everything is fine until I hit the `ON DUPLOCATE KEY UPDATE` where the `updated_at` gets replaced with the `NOW()` timestamp. I tried to remove `currentTime` and `updated_at=NOW()` but would get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./parseTweets.py", line 50, in <module>
    (timestamp, messageId, body, username, dbID, currentTime)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

I don’t want the `updated_at` to be replaced with `created_at` if it’s simply updating the row

Comment: So remove the `updated_at=NOW()` from the `UPDATE` clause? Also, that's vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: Thank you @univerio - how would I fix the SQL injection vulnerability?

Comment: Use parameters in the DBAPI `.execute` call, so instead of `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tbl (foo) VALUES ('%s');" % foo)`, do `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tbl (foo) VALUES (%s);", (foo,))`.